# Switch CSS on fly

Tags: html, css

I was wondering how I can achieve effect like on this page:
http://templateocean.com/stamp/image-bg/2-home-style-two/index.html

On the left side there is panel which allows to adjust template. What I noticed is that I change color, different css is beeing used (blue.css, purple.css etc.) however everything happends "on fly" without reloading web page.

How was it achieved?

Can that be also applied to other elements on webpage like i.e. background changed from picture to video?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for a way without reloading the page, you could use jQuery for it.

If you really want to change a lot of colors on your page, I suggest to add a class to your body. Then you can alter your CSS to your needs.

I've made you this (basic) example to clarify it:

```js
$(function() {
    $('#options button').on('click',function() {
        $('body').addClass( $(this).val() );
    });
});
```

```css
.blue main {
    background: lightblue;
}
.blue main span {
    border: 5px solid blue;
}

.green main {
    background: lightgreen;
}
.green main span {
    border: 5px solid green;
}

.yellow main {
    background: lightyellow;
}
.yellow main span {
    border: 5px solid yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="options">
    <button value="blue">blue</button>
    <button value="green">green</button>
    <button value="yellow">yellow</button>
</div>

<main>This is a text <span>with a span</span></main>
```

[And a JSFiddle to play with it](http://jsfiddle.net/ec9zmp76/)

Comment: +1 The issue with switching out stylesheets is that it may cause a flash of unstyled content as you have to wait while the file is downloaded by the client's browser.

Comment: @asdasd Same happens when the page needs to reload. :). I wonder if that really happens when all the CSS is in one file??

Comment: If you place CSS in the <head> then it will block the rendering of content on page load, unless you specify the async attribute on the <link> tag.

Answer (score 1):

There is some javascript binding to clicks on the color switcher which changes the CSS file reference of a link tag in the header.

Here's the javascript, found in the file [demo.js](http://templateocean.com/stamp/image-bg/5-home-style-five/demo/demo.js).

```
function() {
  var id = $(this).attr("id");

  $("#color-switch").attr("href", "css/colors/" + id + ".css");
}
```

And here's the corresponding stylesheet reference from the document `head` which is being altered by the above code:

```
<!-- COLORS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" id="color-switch" href="css/colors/blue.css">
```